# Graph Topology Profiling

Tags: algorithm, networking, graph-theory

Can anyone suggest me some algorithms that can be used to analyze the graph topology classification? 
Input: Adjacency list with raw graph information.
Output : What kind of graph is it? Currently I want to focus only on Pure Types - **Daisy chain, Mesh, Ring, Star, Tree**.

Which area of algorithm study is responsible for such algorithm? Is it Computational Geometry?

*Edit* - The size of graph will not exceed 32 nodes. However, there will be redundant links between nodes.

*Edit* - I understand that my question might be too broad, but at least give me the clue of what is wrong with the question before down-voting it. Or is it because of my reputation :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by checking that your graph is fully connected.

Then, check the distribution of the nodes' [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)):

- Ring: All nodes would have degree 2
- Daisy chain: all nodes would have degree 2 except for 2 nodes with degree 1 (there are alternative definitions for what a daisy chain is).
- Star: Each node would have degree 1, except for one node with degree n-1
- Tree: The sum of the degrees is 2*(number of nodes-1). Also, if the highest degree is k, then there are at least k nodes with degree 1.
- Mesh: Anything goes...

I don't think there is a 'area' of algorithms that deals with such problems, but the term 'graph classes' is quite common (See for example [here](http://www.ii.uib.no/~federico/papers/Part1.pdf)), though it is not a formal term.

Comment: Can we rely on degree of the nodes? I think it will be tricky to find out the difference between mesh and ring. I think I should mention this in question that input can have redundant links. Graph classes is a good lead.

Comment: You can rely on degree for anything but mesh. Mesh simply means "anything else"...

Comment: I am trying to understand how will that work for the following example. For eg, my graph is 1=2=3, with degree 2, 4 and 2. How should we classify this graph?

Comment: How can you have a node with degree 4 if there are only 3 nodes?

Comment: By having multiple links between two nodes - for high availability.

Comment: This doesn't change the topology. You should remove multiple links first.

Comment: You are right, I can do most of the analysis using DFS and get the back edges and connected components. However, I have one problem. There are redundant edges between nodes. I could remove these edges but this algorithm will be running on a real time system where edges may fail within a span of milliseconds. I doubt this will be efficient but I will still implement and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

To classify a new instance, you need a classification system in the first place!

Putting it another way, your graph (the item to classify) fits somewhere in some kind of data structure of graph topologies (the classification system). The system could be as simple as a list; in which case, you carry out the simple algorithm outlined in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31131437/415384) where the list of topologies is keyed by degree distribution.

A more complex system could be a hierarchical one, similar to biological classification systems. This would only really be necessary for very large numbers of graph topologies, where it would make it faster to classify based on a series of decisions. Essentially a decision tree.

It may be difficult to find much research in this area (for pure graphs) as it's a little hard to think of applications. There are applications for protein fold topologies, but that may not be of interest.